# Creating class library in VS2013 and registering the .tlb so it can be referenced from a VB6 app

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, vb6, class-library

I created a COM class library using my VS2013. I went into the library properties and Compile -> Register for COM interop is checked. I then built the library and see the .tlb file that it generated. At this point I am wondering if there is anything additional that I have to do with the library properties.

I then used RegAsm sample.dll tbl:/sample.tbl

Would the next step be to simply reference the tbl from my VB6 app? I keep getting an error when trying to use the CreateObject function: 429 ActiveX Component can't create object

If my COM library is created properly with GUIDS/Settings based on tutorials and I registered it with RegAsm is there anything that I could be missing?

Comment: Either use the "Register for COM interop" option, with VS running elevated.  *Or* use the correct Regasm.exe command, the /codebase option is required on your dev machine.  And you must use the 32-bit version of Regasm.  Changing the C# code may require re-registering the type library in the VB6 ide.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor if you still have trouble.

Comment: Alright, so on my dev machine I was correct about the only thing needed is Register for COM interop option. Then I bring the library files over to the machine with VB6 and throw them in a directory. Then make sure I use the 32bit RegAsm and the same .NET Framework that the library was created in to register it. Then finally add reference to the .tlb file in the directory in threw it in. Does that seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems registering a COM-Interop-DLL. I finally used the **InstallShield limited edition** setup project to get it running. It's free and replaces the old MS setup project. You need to register to download the software and get a licence.

In the tab **Application Files** add the needed files. In the properties of the files / tab **COM & .NET Settings** set the check box **COM Interop** (this is what I'done) and then create the output.
This is what worked for me.

Christian